С sorting function code verification with FramaC AstraVer
I'm trying to make full code verification for cycle sort function on C. With ASCL annotations we need to "proof" that code is valid. Result is structured in Why3 GUI. I need to cover all goals/theories in safety and behavior sections and current result is:
Safety: 67/68. Need to proof one "loop variant decrease" goal
Behavior: 32/39
Also you can see the results on screenshots



And here is current version of my code:
 /*@ predicate sorted(int *array, integer first, integer last) =
   @    \forall integer i;
   @        first < i < last ==> array[i - 1] <= array[i];
*/

/*@
  @ requires array != \null; 
  @ requires \valid(array + (0 .. size-1));
  @ requires size >= 0; 
  @ assigns array[0..size-1]; 
  @
  @ ensures \forall integer i; 0 <= i < size ==> array[i] >= \old(array[i]);
  @ ensures sorted(array, 0, size);
  */
void sorting(int *array, int size) {
    int bound, idx, x, i, tmp;

    /*@ loop invariant 0 <= bound <= size - 2; 
      @ loop variant size - bound;    
      @*/
    for (bound = 0; bound <= size - 2; bound++) {
        /* @assert bound < size; */ 
        x = array[bound];
        idx = bound;

        /*@ loop invariant bound + 1 <= i <= size;
          @ loop invariant idx >= bound;                           
          @ loop invariant idx <= size-1;                          
          @ loop assigns i, idx;
          @ loop variant size - i;   
          @*/
        for (i = bound + 1; i < size; i++) {
            /*@ assert i < size; @*/
              
            if (array[i] < x) {
                /*@ assert idx + 1 < size; @*/
                idx++;
            }
        }

        if (idx == bound) {
            continue;
        }

        
        /*@ loop invariant idx >= bound && idx < size; 
          @ loop assigns idx;
          @ loop variant size - idx;
        @ */
        while (x == array[idx]) {
            /*@ assert bound <= idx < size; */ 
            idx += 1;
            /*@ assert idx < size; */
        }

        if (idx != bound) {
            /*@ assert idx < size; */
            tmp = array[idx];
            array[idx] = x;
            x = tmp;
        }
    
    /*@
      @ loop invariant bound <= idx < size;
      @ loop assigns idx, tmp, x, i, array[bound .. size-1];
      @ loop variant idx - bound;
    @ */
    
        while (idx != bound) {
            /*@ assert bound <= idx < size;  */
            idx = bound;

            /*@ loop invariant bound < i <= size;     
              @ loop invariant idx >= bound;
              @ loop invariant idx <= size-1;
              @ loop assigns i, idx; 
              @ loop variant size - i;         
             @*/
            for (i = bound + 1; i < size; i++) {
                if (array[i] < x) {
                    /*@ assert idx + 1 < size; */
                    idx += 1;
                }
            }
         
            /*@ assert idx < size; */
            /*@ 
              @ loop invariant idx >= bound && idx < size;
              @ loop assigns idx;
              @ loop variant size - idx;  
              @ */
            while (x == array[idx]) {
                /*@ assert idx + 1 < size; */
                idx += 1;
                /*@ assert idx < size;  */
            }
            /* @assert idx < size; */
            if (x != array[idx]) {
                /* @assert idx < size; */
                tmp = array[idx];
                /* @assert idx < size; */
                array[idx] = x;
                x = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}

The same code with line numeration
Probably some of annotations are redundant but still this is the best result I have got.
As for safety goal "40. Loop variant decrease" I believe it's somewhere in the middle of code, but I can't interpret color highlighting on screenshot. I tried to recount formulas for loop variants and tried many of them but it never leads to reaching goal #40 (furthermore some of proven goals become unproven)
Also I tried to make it in axiomatioc way. Example:
/*@ axiomatic Permut {
  @ predicate permut{L1,L2}(int *t1, int *t2, integer n);
  @     axiom permut_refl{L}:
  @         \forall int *t, integer n; permut{L,L}(t,t,n);
  @     axiom permut_sym{L1,L2}:
  @         \forall int *t1, *t2, integer n;
  @             permut{L1,L2}(t1,t2,n) ==> permut{L2,L1}(t2,t1,n);
  @     axiom permut_trans{L1,L2,L3}:
  @         \forall int *t1, *t2, *t3, integer n;
  @             permut{L1,L2}(t1,t2,n) && permut{L2,L3}(t2,t3,n)
  @             ==> permut{L1,L3}(t1,t3,n);
  @     axiom permut_exchange{L1,L2}:
  @         \forall int *t1, *t2, integer i, j, n;
  @         swap{L1, L2}(t1, t2, i, j, n) ==> permut{L1,L2}(t1,t2,n);
  @ }
  @*/

But it doesnt make any better. Plus using axioms is kind of cheating for verification, so they are undesirable
Probably, ACSL lemmas are the key but I can't construct any valid lemma that helps.
Have you any ideas what annotations I may add to make verification results better?

A hint: Why not using the well tested/verified function qsort()? The average effort of your algorithm is O(n^2), the average effort of qsort is O(N*log(N).

The task is not about algorithm perfomance, need to verify given code

@st_dec, consider what happens when size is pathologically INT_MIN?  Instead of bound <= size - 2; --> bound + 2 <= size;.  No overflow potential.
